# Unix-only package error in R

Tags: r, build, compiler-errors

I'm trying to build the R package [bigmemory](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/index.html) for Windows 8 x64. However, when running `R CMD INSTALL --build bigmemory_4.4.3.tar.gz`, I receive the error `ERROR:  Unix-only package`. I do not know why this is happening, but my guess is that it has something to do with the configure file of the package. I'm using R 3.0.1, 64 bit.

Comment: according to bigrf's documentation, the package I'm installing the dependencies for, bigmemory can be installed for windows: https://github.com/aloysius-lim/bigrf/blob/master/INSTALL-WINDOWS

Comment: Then their documentation is wrong. Read the [bigmemory NEWS](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/NEWS), "Windows support is temporarily suspended due to issues with the Boost headers."

Comment: That sucks. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [bigmemory NEWS](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/NEWS), says "Windows support is temporarily suspended due to issues with the Boost headers." for the most current version of bigmemory.

The package you mention in the comments doesn't depend on a specific version of bigmemory, so you could try to build one of the older versions of bigmemory from [the archive](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/bigmemory/).

Comment: R > 3.0 has changed both support for long ints and how it handles some of the .call() vs. internal() things. If you install a package built under R 2.1x it's going to be a bit risky. Worth a try at though, just write yourself a test suite or two to make sure it both works and you can trust the results.

Answer (score 2):

See this [link](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/NEWS), Windows support has been suspended. It's not your R-version, if you want to make use of it you'll have to use cygwin or install a Linux partition. You can also try the package [ff](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/index.html).

Comment: Using Cygwin will not work... unless you're suggesting they re-build R from source via Cygwin, which is not well-supported.

Comment: You could try a debian or ubuntu partition then. What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Josh, yeah you're right, I think in my head I was thinking of cygwin to access another box/partition or a VM with R installed. Sorry about that.